# Show Notification in Settings ->> Apps ->> XYZ App ->> Show Notification

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, settings

I want to know what does the "Show Notification" checkmark in the Settings actually do in the background ? Does it un-register the push notifications on Global cloud messaging so that the app does not receive notifications at all or does it just disable the notification pop-ups for the app still allowing app to receive messages but just not show it in the notification bar ?

Answer (score 0):

No it does not un-register user from push notifications.

In fact the receiver you have written for receiving notification broadcast will also work. But it will neither play any tone nor vibrate device and notification will not be shown to user in notification bar.

Hope you this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have one more question related to it. If we disable the notifications by uncheck the "Show Notification", then what happens to the app updates when a new version of the app is avaialble ? Do the device still get the notification for the app update ?

Comment: As I said your BroadcastReciever code will be executed any how that is if you are showing popup dialog when app receives update notification will work without sound and vibration and there will be no notification in notification bar

Comment: I am talking about the app update notifications from Google Play store when a new version of the app is available. Will that update notification come if the "Show Notification" is unchecked ?